# Complicated count query

Tags: t-sql

Thanks for your answer guys

However I think I got my required output mixed up.
Here is what I want ( as I am using ORacle DB)

create table TestTable
(
  Bill_date                    DATE,
  Phone_no                     NUMBER(10),
  Planlvl1                     VARCHAR2(20),
  Planlvl2                     VARCHAR2(20)
  Revenue                      NUMBER

)

INSERT INTO TestTable
Values
('1/01/2014' , 64221, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack1', '$23'),
('1/01/2014'' , 64221, 'Bundle', 'PlanA', '$32'),
('1/01/2014' , 65211, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack2', '$3'),
('1/01/2014' , 65211, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack1', '$23'),
('1/01/2014' , 66211, 'Bundle', 'PlanB', '$34'),
('1/01/2014' , 66211, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack2', '$3'),
('1/01/2014' , 66222, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack1', '$23'),
('1/01/2014' , 66222, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack2', '$3'),
('1/01/2014' , 66222, 'Bundle', 'PlanB', '$65'),
('1/01/2014' , 32444, 'Non_bundle', 'Casual1', '$32'),
('1/01/2014' , 324441, 'Non_bundle', 'Casual2', '$76'),
('1/01/2014' , 65444, 'Non_bundle', 'Casual1', '$12'),
('1/01/2014' , 65444, 'Bundle', 'PlanB', '$98'),
('1/01/2014' , 54322, 'Bundle', 'PlanA', '$12'),
('1/01/2014' , 54322, 'Non_bundle', 'Casual', '$12')

Expected Outcome:
Bill_date PlanLvl2 PhonenoCount
'01/01/2014' 'SpecialPack1' 1

'01/01/2014' 'SpecialPack2' 3

'01/01/2014' 'Casual1' 1

'01/01/2014' 'Casual2' 1

'01/01/2014' 'PlanA' 1

'01/01/2014' 'PlanB' 1

As I mentioned , 'SpecialPack2' will get a preference over special pack 1 if a phone no has got both of these .

Hope its clearer

Basically The most expensive plan count logic applies  in the case when a phone no has more then 1 'Special Packs' and no other type of plans.
In  case where a phone no has a special pack and other plan , then we do not need to count the ph no under that 'non special' plan.

I have a test table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
 (`Bill_date` datetime, `Phone_no` int, `Planlvl1` varchar(10), `PlanLvl2` varchar(12), `revenue` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO TestTable
 (`Bill_date`, `Phone_no`, `Planlvl1`, `PlanLvl2`, `revenue`)
VALUES
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 64221, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack1', '$23'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 64221, 'Bundle', 'PlanA', '$32'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 65211, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack2', '$3'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 65211, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack1', '$23'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 66211, 'Bundle', 'PlanB', '$34'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 66211, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack2', '$3'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 66222, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack1', '$23'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 66222, 'Bundle', 'SpecialPack2', '$3'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 66222, 'Bundle', 'PlanB', '$65'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 32444, 'Non_bundle', 'Casual1', '$32'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 324441, 'Non_bundle', 'Casual2', '$76'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 65444, 'Non_bundle', 'Casual1', '$12'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 65444, 'Bundle', 'PlanB', '$98'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 54322, 'Bundle', 'PlanA', '$12'),
 ('2014-01-01 13:00:00', 54322, 'Non_bundle', 'Casual', '$12')
;
```

Basically I have to count all the phone nos grouped by plans in a certain way:

If PlanLvl1 = Bundle, then I have to look  at planLvl2 and see if that phone no has ' SpecialPack%' ,and also another plan,them 'Special pack' gets the priority and the phone no gets counted in the special pack.

In case when PlanLvl1 = Bundle and a phone no has both 'Special Packs' as their plans, then the phone no will be counted under the 'Special Pack' with higher Revenue.

In case where PalnLvl is 'Bundle' and a phone no has multiple 'Special Packs' and a non special, that ph no will only be counted once under 'Special Pack; of higher rev as compared to the special pack of lower rev.

Now there are also PlanLvl1 which are 'Non_Bundles' which means they do not have any 'SpecialPacks' but if a ph no with 'NonBundle' plan has 2 different plans under planLvl2, we need to count that ph no for eack planLvl2..

Then there is a scenario where a ph no can have bundles as well as non bundles and in that case we just have to count that ph no in bundles and not in non-bundles.

Here is the expected outcome:

```
Bill_date PlanLvl2 PhonenoCount

01/01/2014 SpecialPack1 3

01/01/2014 SpecialPack2 1

01/01/2014 Casual1 0

01/01/2014 Casual2 1

01/01/2014 PlanA 1

01/01/2014 PlanB 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason to put the $ sign in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef37a/18), note there's no "SpecialPack2" because all number also got SpecialPack1 and aggregates values ignores nulls, so no zero is returned.

Note the problem is not the aggregate but the "no count this" logic.
Also I noted most of this logic is to count only the most expensive plans, in that case the logic can be simplified a lot.
btw, persisting that values as a string (and with a leading '$') is a very poor practice.

```
select bill_date
, case 
when planlvl1 = 'Bundle' and planlvl2 like 'SpecialPack%' then planlvl2
when planlvl1 = 'Bundle' then planlvl2
when planlvl1 = 'Non_bundle' then planlvl2
else planlvl1 end as PlanLvl2
, count(phone_no) as PhonenoCount
from
(
select Bill_date, Phone_no, Planlvl1, PlanLvl2, cast(substring(revenue, 2, 20) as float) as revenue
  from testTable
  where 
  (
    planlvl1 = 'Bundle'
    and 
    ( 
      (planlvl2 like 'SpecialPack%'
        and cast(substring(revenue, 2, 20) as float) = (select max(cast(substring(t1.revenue, 2, 20) as float)) from testTable t1 where t1.phone_no = phone_no and planlvl2 like 'SpecialPack%')
       )
     or
     (planlvl2 not like 'SpecialPack%'
      and phone_no not in (select phone_no from testTable where planlvl2 like 'SpecialPack%')
      )
    )
  )
  or (planlvl1 = 'Non_bundle' and phone_no not in (select phone_no from testTable where Planlvl1 = 'Bundle')
      and cast(substring(revenue, 2, 20) as float) = (select max(cast(substring(t1.revenue, 2, 20) as float)) from testTable t1 where t1.phone_no = phone_no and planlvl1 = 'Non_bundle')
     )

) as ignore_duplicates
group by bill_date
, case 
when planlvl1 = 'Bundle' and planlvl2 like 'SpecialPack%' then planlvl2
when planlvl1 = 'Bundle' then planlvl2
when planlvl1 = 'Non_bundle' then planlvl2
else planlvl1 end
```